# A sum involving Mobius function and fractional parts

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am wondering if there are known partial sum estimates involving fractional parts and Mobius function. More specifically, consider the following sum:

$$S(x):=\sum_{n\leq x}\dfrac{\mu(n)-\mu(n-1)}{n}\psi\left(\dfrac{x}{n}\right)$$ 
where $\psi(x):=\left\{x\right\}-\dfrac{1}{2}$ ($\{x\}$ represents fractional part of $x$).

By rearrangement $S(x)$ becomes
\begin{eqnarray}
S(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}\mu(n)\left(\dfrac{\psi(\frac{x}{n})}{n}-\dfrac{\psi\left(\frac{x}{n+1}\right)}{n+1}\right)+O(1/x)
\end{eqnarray}
Although one can obtain trivial bounds like $O(\log x)$, or probably slight improvements of it, I wanted to ask if this sum is actually $o(1)$.

Any help/insight is appreciated.

Comment: For $n> x^{1/2+ \delta}$, I think one can get big savings in this sum using the approximate continuity of $\psi \left(\frac{x}{n} \right)$. But it seems hard to get savings for small $n$. In particular I can choose $x$ so that the fractional parts of $x/p$ for $p$ primes less than $\log x$ are basically arbitrary, so it's hard to see how one could get a bound better than $\log \log \log x$ without being very clever.

Comment: Note that $\psi(\frac a n)$ is the value of the partial zeta function $\zeta_{a, n}(s)$ at $s=-1$.

Comment: @WhatsUp What do you mean with the partial zeta function? And how does your claim follow from it?

Comment: @Wojowu I mean $\zeta_{a, n}(s) = \sum_{m > 0\\m \equiv a \mod n} \frac{1}{m^s}$. It's a standard fact that $\zeta_{a, n}(-k)$ is equal to $B_{k+1}(\{\frac{a}{n}\})$ (maybe up to some factor), where $B_k$ is the Bernoulli polynomial. So my comment above is slightly wrong as it's probably the value at $s = 0$. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function#Relation_to_Bernoulli_polynomials